# echo json_encode($array) no funciona

Tags: php

Buen dia, tengo el siguiente script PHP el cual recorre una consulta mysqli donde hay 33 productos, la consulta aqui no importa pues esta bien, al hacer echo dentro de un while del campo nombre, me arroja los 33 nombres, lo mismo para valor, el problema es al hacer echo json_encode del array completo una vez construido al finalizar el while

Lo necesitaré para enviarlo de vuelta por ajax al JS

```
<?php
        $consulta_productos = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM productos");
        
            while($array_producto = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_productos))
              {        
                $nombre = $array_producto['nombre'];
//esto echo funciona bien pues muestra los 33 nombres
                //echo $nombre;        
                $valor = $array_producto['valor']; 
//este echo tambien muestra los 33 valores
                //echo $valor;
                $array_producto_final[] = array("nombre" => $nombre,"valor" => $valor);
              }
        //aqui es donde no muestra el array
               echo json_encode($array_producto_final);
        //si aca hago un var_dump del array, si lo muestra con los 33 productos
 ?>
```

Respuesta del servidor

[image: respuesta al recorrer los 33 productos]

Lo curioso es que cambié la consulta colocando el valor "850" para probar y en ese caso si funciona correctamente el json encode imprimiendo todos los productos que tienen valor 850

```
$consulta_productos = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM productos WHERE valor = 850);
```

[image: echo json_encode del array productos con valor 850]

pienso que seria algo en la base de datos, pero entonces, si es asi, por que el var_dump si lo muestra bien al consultar todos los 33 productos

aqui la tabla

[image: tabla productos]

Alguna idea?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta el texto, no la imagen, del  `var_dump` completo? Lo que se me ocurre es que cuando consultas todos los productos puede haber algún dato en los resultados que esté rompiendo el json, por problemas de codificación u otros.

Comment: Tienes [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/427462/autocompletar-no-funciona-con-cierto-texto-digitado) donde también mencionas problemas con la misma tabla. En PHPMyAdmin selecciona esa tabla, ve a la pestaña Operaciones y haz clic en los enlaces "Optimizar tabla" y "Reparar tabla" para ver si eso ayuda.

Comment: Continuando con lo mencionado por @A.Cedano, ¿Qué codificación tiene la tabla?